# Extract month, day, and year from DateTime date

Tags: perl

I have a variable `$nowDate` holding the current date as a [`DateTime`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) object.

Now I need to pull the month, day and year from that variable and assign them to their own variables. How would I go about doing that?

```
my $nowDate = DateTime->now(time_zone => 'local');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to get them explicitly

```
my $nowDate = DateTime->now(time_zone => 'local');

my ($month, $day, $year) = ($nowDate->month, $nowDate->day, $nowDate->year);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/%7Edrolsky/DateTime-1.42/lib/DateTime.pm) has methods for these, `year` (yyyy), `month` (1-12), and `day` (1-31)

```
my ($year, $month, $day) = map { $nowDate->$_ } qw(year month day);
```

This may return a single-digit month or day, such as `5` for May (not `05`). So you may want

```
my ($year, $month, $day) = map { sprintf "%02d", $nowDate->$_ }
```

if your application relies on the two-digit format.

Or you can pull them out of `$nowDate`, for example

```
my ($year, $month, $day) = split '-', $nowDate->ymd;            # 2017-05-09
```

or

```
my ($year, $month, $day) = unpack "A4A2A2", $nowDate->ymd('');  # 20170509
```

The method `ymd` allows to specify the separator, the default being `-`. See documentation.

Comment: Since `ymd` and family just do explicit calls to the accessors (or pull the value straight out of the hash) and use `sprintf` to build the result, I think there's a good case for checking `wantarray` and returning a list of values in scalar context. Of course, by now such a change would break some strange code that called `my @dmy = $date->dmy`.

Comment: @Borodin  I don't understand -- `ymd` isn't context sensitive? Do you mean to wrap this in a sub?  I don't see what you mean by "_returning a list of values in scalar context_", can you explain? I have all  kinds of utility subs for `DateTime` in a certain project, always looking for ideas. (The question is too basic -- I wanted to show this since the asker or a visitor are likely unaware of it, and to provide a scoop of how one can use it.)

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I was lamenting the way the module is written. As it stands, `ymd` returns a single `YYYY-MM-DD` string in any context, when it would have been so easy to make it return `(YYYY, MM, DD)` in list context, which would have solved the OP's problem instantly. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Borodin  Ah, yes!  My sentiment exactly, not only on this one.  I had to write  a bunch of utility subs in any project that relies heavily on this module. I often needed to "massage" the provided methods to get what I need and that distracts from the program flow. I felt that other conviniences could have been provided as well and considered subclassing it.  It's a very useful piece of work of course, many thanks to authors.  (But I'm still on the lookout for a much lighter basic one for simple uses, with a reasonable interface.)

Comment: I wouldn't hesitate to monkey-patch it. The code for `ymd` et al is only two or three lines. What bothers me is that a `DateTime` object weighs in at around a kilobyte, while a `Time::Piece` is about 150 bytes. Have you seen [DateTime::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Tiny)? It may be what you want, and size-wise it's between the two at 500B.

Comment: @Borodin Thank you! I think I've seen it before and found it a bit too short on functionality.  (No even `ymd` for example. The CPAN page lists it, btw.) But when I look at it now -- it's a perfect starting point to add to, while before that didn't even occur to me. It is an interesting thing how smoothly perceptions can evolve, sometimes for very subtle reasons, to the point of getting turned around; it was "no" before and it is "yes" now.

Comment: @Borodin  Yes, `DateTime` is just too heavy for some uses.  I wrote some utility programs here that are used across various languagues and tools as command-line programs, tens (or hundreds) of thousand times per their run.  (It was required that it is Perl, I did beg for C or at least C++.)  I couldn't use `DateTime`.  Loading was just prohibitive. (It can't be made resident or anything such.)